# Blog.php or how to display recent posts?

Tags: htaccess, blog-page, linking

I created a home.php which doesn't display the recent posts in the standard-blog-style.
Just have a look at [my website](http://www.zoomingjapan.com) to see what I mean.
I want to create a link that leads to something like "http://..../blog" where the recent posts are displayed "normally".
I know how to do that, but what I don't know is how to create that new "link" that leads to ".../blog".

Is it possible to create a "blog.php" just like a "home.php" where the recent posts will be displayed?

But even if I create a "blog.php" I will get a 404 error message when clicking on "http://.../blog".

I hope you get what I mean and can help me out here a bit.
Do I have to modify the htaccess thingie for that or what? :/

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `home.php` for static home page, use `front-page.php` or any other page template instead.

Also see Codex page for [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)